# Importing spring boot jar into another app without @ComponentScan and Xml Configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm looking for a generic/clean solution to import a spring boot jar application into another spring boot application without doing @ComponentScan(package name of the application), without the xml configuration.

If I didn't say @Componentscan in the base application, @Autowired is not working, which is quite understandable.

So in general writing libraries with spring boot is not a ideal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I went with @Import(ApplicationConfiguration)which I find it quite neat.

I had a multi-level project structure so on each of the sub-module created a configuration file which initiate the required beans and then in the parent module, I have used @Import.